# Is it possible to use the RFID-RC522 with ISO 14443-4/APDU-based smartcards protocol?

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, hce

I'm currently working in an android application that use Host-Based Card Emulation. Well I have a NFC reader RC522 and my goal is simulate a tag that has a password and once the user touch the reader, this password is transferred to the Arduino for further processing. 
I've search and saw that HCE uses APDU to identify with service the reader want start up. In this sense, I could not found how to implement that using Arduino code, so I would like to know if the RC522 can fit to use with HCE in android.

Thanks in advance.
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

RC522 is ISO14443 card, you need ISO14444 card.

Please look:
[1]: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/issues/88
[2]: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/issues/220
[3]: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf